# How to change or delete the entries in the Google Bar App Launcher?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

First of all:

What is the Google Bar App Launcher?

The little icon on the *New Tab Page* in the upper right corner, a small 3x3 grid symbol.

This thing:

[image: [App Launcher screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRqp3.jpg)]

You can customize this menu, i.e. rearrange the items, or add new ones.
 Google luckily has a nice help page:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1714464?hl=en&ref_topic=28726

(See under *Customize your menu*)

But now, the million dollar question is:

How do I remove an entry again? For example, these entries:

[image]

Comment: "caring about usability" It's not about usability, it's about discouraging spammers abusing Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, I get that. Right idea in principle, but I still think the limitations are too tight, discouraging new and interested users more than spammers in the end. But the question basically looks as intended now, so it's okay. Although my post scriptum was deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Chrome (which includes Developer Tools), right-click the app you want to remove and pick Inspect, then right-click the applicable `<li class="gb_Z" ...` HTML script element and pick Delete Element. The app will disappear from the app launcher as desired. Now drag any remaining app to a new location within the app launcher; this is necessary to save the result.

Google makes it easy to add and rearrange apps in the app launcher; they need to provide a convenient way to delete apps, too.

Comment: Yes! This is actually working! Although it's kind of an ugly workaround, but apparently the developers of Google Chrome did not really think about removing items from their App launcher.

Answer (score 0):

Organizing your apps

Add apps: Go to the Chrome Web Store chrome store.

Add webpages: Open the webpage and click More More  > More tools > Add to shelf > Add.

**Remove apps: Right-click the icon and select Remove from Chrome.**

Scroll through apps: Click the blue bars at the bottom.

Move apps: Click and hold an app and move it.

Search for apps: Type the name of your app into the search box.

Create folders: Click and drag an app on top of another app to bundle them together in a folder. To give the folder a name, click the folder. To remove an app from a folder, click the folder, then click and drag the app out.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not right. The Launcher menu in the Google Bar is not the same as Apps for Chrome. What you are talking about is the Apps tab, which can be found with this address: chrome://apps/.  There you can make a right-click and select "Remove from Chrome", but the entries show in the screenshot above **do not** have this context menu option.  This is something different.